# How can I use this table design with valid markup?

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the tables but use css to achieve the same positioning result with a strict doctype. This is the design that does exactly what I need.

Notice the `<br>` tags in the last (bottom) `<td>` cell. As this area grows, the position of the data within two other `<td>` cells above it do not change position.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="400" height="100%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">ds</td> <----- The position here is important
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="bottom">ds</td> <----- The position here is important
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">ada adf ad<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to duplicate this in a div structure or use tables as a layout for your website?

Comment: Hi Kyle, I want to keep the tables for the structure but position the 2 cells that I've marked as important with css.

Comment: Tables are an old form of layout construction, tables are fine touse if you're using tabular data. But as for layout, you really should switch to semantic div/css layouts. This layout can be easily simulated with semantic HTML (divs and stuff).

Comment: Meh... if you can't care enough about semantics to actually use the correct markup for your webpages, then why would you care about your HTML validating?

Comment: Webpage? Who said it was a webpage? I suppose you were the troll that voted the post down, right? :)

Comment: it's HTML markup, so yes, it's a webpage.

Answer (score 3):

I made an example [for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/wMxHH/) to show you how easy it is to duplicate that table with Divs and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div id="main-div-wrap">
                <div class="left-content">
                <span class="top">ds</span>
                <span class="bottom">ds</span>
                </div>
                <div class="right-content">
                    ada adf ad
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-div-wrap
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.left-content
{
    width: 18%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.right-content
{
    margin-left; 18%;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.top 
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
}

.bottom 
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

All semantic, no hacks, will validate and if you need to change it for browsers, theres [more than](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/CSS-Browser-detection-using-jQuery-instead-of-hacks.aspx) [enough tools](http://stylizedweb.com/2008/02/26/css-browser-selector/) [out there to help you](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with "keep the tables for the structure", but I guess you what something like this, however if the content is too short, then the "top" and "bottom" texts will overlap.

http://jsfiddle.net/HsmKA/

---

Variant with CSS styled tables:

http://jsfiddle.net/JmQ55/

Comment: RoToRa, Thanks. I'll check it out now.

Comment: RoToRa, THanks for that. What I was hoping to do was to keep my tables but maybe add inline css to it to achieve the same result. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand which of the tables you want to keep and why. Maybe you should explain what kind of content it is you have.

Comment: The entire site is done in tables. I don't want to touch them at this point. There is a box that needs to rest on the bottom left column and is where I'm having the issue. I want to keep all of the tables but need to delete the `valign` attributes.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand. However there is no real point IMHO. You'd just replace the `valign` attributes with classes hardly marking anything much more "better".

Comment: Actually what I said is not true. Added a "table styled with CSS" variant.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all you want [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#diffs).

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a tables word myself I've always found the DIV layout a pain in the a$$.
Check out [blue print css](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) its a very easy to use CSS framework. Might sort you out

Comment: Yes sir! I don't think css is worth the headache. Too many hacks are needed as I'm sure you're aware. I;ll check out the link you have, thanks!

Comment: Why did you get down voted? I think your suggestion is pretty darn good.

Comment: Not sure maybe it was those dollar signs after the a :)

Comment: also http://html5boilerplate.com/ is useful resource not specifically for what your after tho.

Comment: Wow, if that's the case then that explains why this country is in the shape it's in. :)

Comment: I just downloaded blueprint. do I plug in my table design or how does that work exactly?

Comment: @Rui Carneiro, lol.. I agree. That's where I'm at with the whole css thing too. :) Thanks for sharin

Comment: @Rui don't forget the <sarcasm> tags in the source of that page ;)